# I thought+ past simple or perfect

Tags: past-perfect

1 When I entered the room she cleaned  windows

2 When I entered the room she had cleaned windows

These examples are clear to me. 1 prpbably both actions at the same time 2 first cleaning that entering. But, what about this?

3 I thought she had kids

4 I thought she had had kids

I'd like to say that 4 is correct because first she had kids and later " I thought". Now I see other explanation.
3 and 4 in the presence

3 I think she has kids

4 I think she had kids

Does it work in a sense like  the reported speech and therefore the meaning is prettg much the same?

Comment: The past perfect is **always** accompanied by another past tense either stated or implied. I thought she had had kids when I **saw** the pictures on the mantlepiece. This has been explained many, many times here. So, you can do a search for that. It is not about reported speech here at all.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to reread your posts and correct the spelling?

Comment: 1 I saw she ate vs 2  I saw she had estan. I understand that 2 shows first she ate then I saw some proof of that we have two activities seeing and esating but I struggle with I thought you were right vs I thought you had been right. Do we treat thought as an activity too?

Comment: I've explained it already. In my first comment.

Comment: No you didn't..

Comment: No you didn't explain anything. We could say I saw she ate or I saw she had eaten. Here we don't need any additoonal sentence. Why is that?

Comment: **The past perfect is always accompanied by another past tense either stated or implied. I thought she had had kids when I saw the pictures on the mantlepiece**. I saw (past tense) she had eaten (past perfect). **Like I said**,  the PP is always accompanied by another tense in the past.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151307/discussion-between-gram-and-lambie).